# My USB security key is set up, but still not an option on Win10 login screen

Tags: windows-10, security, windows-hello

I have a `FEITIAN BioPass K27 USB Security Key` that I am trying to use to log in to my Windows 10 (Version 2004 - 19041.450) PC. I have gone through all the setup steps as shown below, including setting up a PIN linked to the USB key (Windows Hello):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And yet, in the end, this **security key** login option doesn't appear on my windows login screen:

[image]

This personal PC is not linked to Azure, it's not on a company domain, etc...but I fear that all this stuff is required as per [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/how-to-password-less-fido2-security-key-sign-in-to-windows-10/ba-p/1434583). Did MS really not provide a way for simple, isolated, personal computers to login with a USB key??

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't yet updated to 20H2 build?

Comment: music, will this make any difference in security key usage?

Comment: Before I'd found the marked duplicate, I'd assume that newer versions are more likely to support advanced features. Also, there's not really a generally compelling reason not to.